# Android/Xamarin styling a button image

Tags: android, xamarin

can anybody help me pointing out the documentation with the *options* related to styling a background in Xamarin/Android ? The UI designer is horrible, i can't find a way to use both text and image in a button AND styling the background (i,e, i'd want to anchor the BG only to a corner, with a fixed size/scaling)

I can't find it by googling, can anyone shame me and pointing me in the right direction? thanks

Comment: See: https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui

Answer (score 0):

actually the solution is to use custom listviews

http://javatechig.com/xamarin/listview-example-in-xamarin-android